# Chat background changed today

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, chat

Earlier today, the background in chat changed.  At least it did for a large band on the bottom of the chat box:

[image: Screenshot showing the issue.]

As you can see, this makes reading the text extremely difficult.  The chat transcript page has the same issue, only worse as it covers all the text instead of just the bottom chunk.

The same background pattern can be found [on this page](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=scifi.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It's happened on the "list of rooms about SciFi" page, too.

Comment: It seems the universe leaked. we're fixing the leak as we speak.

Comment: Everyone evacuate as Fringe Division deploys the amber!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the css was incorrectly using our "sandbox" area for the images. Guess what - if somebody changes what we are prototyping - things go bad!

Building out now...

Answer (score 0):

Just for the case this persists, a workaround that might work for the time being is scaling the page up. Everything gets huge, but the orange background is pushed beyond the visible portion of the page.

YMMV